# How to restart other program in python?

Tags: python, windows

I have python **script** that interacts with other windows **program**. Occasionally this program crashes and I get an error in script. How can I shut down this program and restart it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/F", "/T", "/IM", "progname.exe"])  # forced killing, with childs, by name
subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Path\To\Folder\progname.exe", "--fast"])
```